# Its good practice do my own security logic?

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, password-encryption

I am building an e-commerce where the people must register and login in the application. I was taking a look to Spring Security i am wondering if is OK do it by myself the password encryption, the rol management (i have a table in database) , the login etc. I would like to do my own code for that. I mean use the old school style.

My question is: What do you think about it? I am doing bad. What benefits or disanvatages in that.?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Doing any form of custom security logic is always bad practice.**

Thats why there are security standards defined in RFCs, like oauth2, basic auth, form login etc, to avoid custom security.

Spring security has 1000s of unit tests, it is open source, has been battle tested in thousands and thousands of production applications. Reviewed by hundreds of developers and improved over several years.

If doing custom logic, **all it takes is one critical bug and your custom security may be worthless**.

Can you afford that risk? probably not.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I will take seriously the security from now.

Comment: please mark this as the answer if you feel it answered your question.